# Laravel only one of two routes accessible at a time

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6

If I have two routes A and B in my web.php. How can I make a middleware check like this:

```
if (something in my database have status == 0) {
    return $next($request); ROUTE A
} else {
    return $next($request); ROUTE B
}
```

I mentioned `return $next($request);` because there is one condition in this, I **don't want the routes to be both accessible at the same time**. So for example if I go to `url/routeA` if the condition is met allow if not show route B. The same goes for route B.

The logic would be like this users chooses an item from a list (in the db the list is represented like this: `list` with `id,name,status`) if the status is 0 show route A if status is 1 show route B. If I try to visit `url/routeB?listID1` directly check condition (for `id1`) and show either route A or B.

Only 0 or 1 in the status. If the status is 1 all users would be accessing routeB directly, if the status is 0 the first users to get there would access routeA do some action (that would set the status to 1) get redirected to routeB. Next users after him will reach routeB directly

Comment: Different status for each user?

Comment: Only 0 or 1 in the status. If the status is 1 all users would be accessing routeB directly, if the status is 0 the first users to get there would access routeA do some action (that would set the status to 1) get redirected to routeB. Next users after him will reach routeB directly.

Comment: Surely a redirect when they do the action, and then all other users will hit the else condition in the middleware

Comment: Yes but how do I set the condition?

Comment: Did you think about `laravel policy` to resolve your purpose?.

Comment: Never used `laravel policy` can you please provide an example?

Comment: `if (DB::table('my_table')->value('status') == 0) { /**/ } else { /**/ }` If you have models then replace the `DB::table` with the model. Also, I'm not sure what your query will be. Read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries). I also recommend reading tutorials on how Laravel works. You clearly haven't got basic knowledge down. Do some tutorials first, it will greatly help you in the future.

Comment: Can I use `if statements` directly in the web.php route file? and if I can what is the point of `Route::group` from the answer below, can't I just use the if without the `Route::group`?

Comment: Of course you can. Route group allows you to add prefix and various other things to routes. So you don't have to add the same code over and over again. Again, I reiterate, [**read the docs**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-groups)

Comment: How can I use something like `$request->route('id');` to retrieve some parameter from another route?

Comment: I mean I need to use a parameter in the if statement. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want, you can just do a redirect from your middleware:

```
if (something in my database have status == 0) {
    return redirect()->route('route_a_name');
} else {
    return redirect()->route('route_b_name');
}
```

Just make sure you name your routes in your `routes/web.php`.

Example:

```
Route::get('/route_a', 'YourController@RouteA')->name('route_a_name');
```

**Edit**:

Based on the additional info you provided, a middleware for what you are trying to achieve is kind of over the top. Instead you could simply use a single route and pass in the status parameter. For more info on routing parameters see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters.

Example:

```
Route::get('/your_route/{status}', 'YourController@ControllerAction');
```

Then in your controller, handle the logic based on the status:

```
function ControllerAction(Request $request, $status) {
    if ($status == 0) {
        //Show view for A
    } else {
        //Show view for B
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want the routes to be accessible via url unelss the condition is checked. So I don't want to just add the routes in the web.php and let em be accessed freely

Comment: Why use a middleware then? Why not just have one route and pass in the status? e.g. `Route::get('/your_route/{status}', 'YourController@YourAction')`

Comment: You are right, I made only 1 route, I checked the status in the controller and returned the appropriate view based on the status. Please edit your answer with this and I will vote it correct. Thank you.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use route name and simply use it any where.

```
  //define route
  Route::get('/A', 'ControllerA@methodA')->name('A');
  Route::get('/B', 'ControllerB@methodB')->name('B');
```

> In your controller simply use **route name**

```
   $routeName = ['A','B']; //route name
   If (something in my database have status == 0) {
     return Redirect::route($routeName[0]); //ROUTE A
   } else {
      return Redirect::route($routeName[1]); //ROUTE B
   }
```

> Otherwise you can do something getting route group parameter

```
  Route::group(['prefix' => '/test/{id}'], function() {
   //you can't access parameter directly here 
    $id = explode('test/',url()->current())[1]; //get parameter with different way
    if($id == 1){
       exit('do something');
    }else{
        exit('do others');
    }
 });
```

Comment: I'd probably not have an array of route names, it just adds a layer of complexity. Unless you have lots of routes, just write them in place of the array.

Comment: @JustCarty you are right in this purpose but I think it's helpful when more condition going on.

Comment: I don't want the routes to be accessible via url unless the condition is checked. So I don't want to just add the routes in the web.php and let them be accessed freely. I need the if statement in the `//define routes`. I don't know how to access a parameter from another routes in the `if` statement.

Comment: @Victordb I don't sure do you want something like this 'Route::get('/route/{id}',function($id){
    if($id==1){
        //do something
    }
    else{
         //do others
   }
});'

Comment: Yes but for some reason I can't use it in `Route::group(['prefix' => '/'], function($id)`.

Comment: Hi @Victordb I edit my answer on your last comment maybe it's help you to gain your challenge. Thanks

Comment: I ended up doing only one route, check the condition inside the controller and return the appropriate view. I appreciate your help. Thank you!!!